# Adding an outline around a snake in snake game

Tags: python, pygame

Im making a snake game and I thought that it would realy cool if there was an outline to the snake. But just drawing a box around each body part in the snake looks bad. So I want to add an outline to only the edges of the snake, but im lost on how one would do/start it.

The body is an array full of pygame Rectangles:

```py
self.body = [
   pygame.Rect(100, 100, 50, 50)
   pygame.Rect(150, 100, 50, 50)
   pygame.Rect(200, 100, 50, 50)
]
```

I have it loop through the body and draw each square in the body

```py
for i in self.body:
   #etc
```

I would assume youd want to draw the outlines of the body when drawing the body but I dont quite know the logic on how it would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, for each side of a rectangle, you need to check if it is docked to another rectangle in the list, and draw a line segment along that side if it is not docked.

Iterate through all rectangles and create a list of adjacent rectangles:

```py
for i, r in enumerate(rectangles):
    neighbours = rectangles[i-1:i] + rectangles[i+1:i+2]
```

Since the rectangles do not overlap, they do not collide and a collision check fails. Therefore, a rectangle must be modified, it can either be inflated on one side or moved to one side. In my solution, I choose to [`move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) the rectangle by 1 to one side and check that the rectangle does not collide with any of the adjacent rectangles. Use [`pygame.Rect.collidelist`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) for the collision test. This method returns the index of the first rectangle in the list where a collision was detected, otherwise -1. e.g.:

```py
right_test_rect = r.move(1, 0)
if right_test_rect.collidelist(neighbours) < 0:
    # [...]
```

Instead of drawing thick lines with `pygame.draw.line` I decided to draw rectangles thinly with `pygame.draw.rect`. `pygame.draw.line` draws a line between 2 coordinates and inflates the line on both sides. However, I would like to specify the exact rectangular area to be filled.

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def drawOutline(surf, rectangles, color, width):
    for r in rectangles:
        corners = [
            (r.left, r.top), (r.right-width, r.top), 
            (r.left, r.bottom-width), (r.right-width, r.bottom-width),
        ]
        for c in corners:
            pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, (*c, width, width))

    for i, r in enumerate(rectangles):
        neighbours = rectangles[i-1:i] + rectangles[i+1:i+2]
        sides = [
            (r.move(-1,  0), (r.left, r.top+width, width, r.height-2*width)),
            (r.move( 1,  0), (r.right-width, r.top+width, width, r.height-2*width)),
            (r.move( 0, -1), (r.left+width, r.top, r.width-2*width, width)),
            (r.move( 0,  1), (r.left+width, r.bottom-width, r.width-2*width, width)),
        ]
        for test_rect, line in sides:
            if test_rect.collidelist(neighbours) < 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, line)

body = [
   pygame.Rect(50, 100, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(100, 100, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(150, 100, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(200, 100, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(200, 150, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(150, 150, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(100, 150, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(100, 200, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(100, 250, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(150, 250, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(200, 250, 50, 50),
   pygame.Rect(250, 250, 50, 50),
]

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    drawOutline(window, body, "yellow", 3)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```